# How to create table in hbase using pyspark?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, hbase

I wants to create new hbase table if not exist in namespace/hbase from pyspark code for storing data, can someone help me do this task?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is that using happybase. You can find document here
[happybase](https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It is an example below

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                                            
emp                                                                                                                                                              
1 row(s) in 0.7750 seconds

=> ["emp"]
```

There is only one table and I will create new table which is called my_table with using Spark

```
>>> import happybase
>>> host = 'your host'
>>> connection = happybase.Connection(host = host) #not specify port
>>> connection.create_table(
...     'my_table',
...     {'col1': dict(), # it uses defaults, if you want you can define column definitions
...      'col2': dict(),
...      'col3': dict()
...     }
... )
```

And check hbase

```
hbase(main):002:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                                            
emp                                                                                                                                                              
my_table                                                                                                                                                         
2 row(s) in 0.0660 seconds

=> ["emp", "my_table"]
```

New table is created. You can read tables in Spark via happybase as well.

```
>>> import happybase
>>> host = 'your host'
>>> connection = happybase.Connection(host = host) #not specify port
>>> table = connection.table('emp')
>>> table.row('1')
{b'personal data:name': b'raju'}
```